# How can I pass process.env from main to my npm package

Tags: node.js, webpack

In my npm package I want to access `process.env.MYCUSTOMVAR`, which is from  `main.app`.  When I try to print `process.env.MYCUSTOMVAR` in the package, it returns `{}`.  How can I access this variable?

In case it is relevant: my npm package has built using babel from webpack build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider instead exporting that object in main.app and accessing it from external scripts using the `require` syntax:

```
// main.app.js
// ...whatever code you have...
module.exports.MYCUSTOMVAR = process.env.MYCUSTOMVAR;

// your_package.js
var MYCUSTOMVAR = require("./main.app").MYCUSTOMVAR;
```

That should work!